# What does text in `{ }` in MSDN syntax documentation mean?

Tags: syntax, msdn

I am reading a MSDN documentation about EMFSPOOL Records. In the record syntax chapter, the grammar is presented as followed:

```
<emf_spool_format> ::= <Header_record>
      [ <EMRI_PS_JOB_DATA_record> ]
      { <other_records> }
       <page_offset_records>  

<other_records> ::= <page_content_records> |
      <font_definition_records> |
      <font_offset_records> |
      <EMRI_DEVMODE_record> |
      <EMRI_PRESTARTPAGE_record>
```

etc.
I know that text in `[ ]` means 'optional', but what does text in `{ }` mean?
Is it perhaps a more general convention of writing documentation like this?

This is the link with the full syntax:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231157.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a more thorough search in MSDN, I found out that this is Extended Backus–Naur Form (EBNF) notation. As a result an expression in `{ }` means an expression repeated zero or more times.